# C++ class: How to use dict["hello"]=20; like Python

Tags: python, c++, class, overloading

It's my first time asking a question on Stack Overflow.

As titled, I want to make a simple dictionary.

Here is my C++ code:

```
class Dict
{
public:
    Dict(string key, int value);
    ~Dict();
    void append(string key, int value);
    int operator[](string search);
    //int operator=(int value);

private:

    string* keys;
    int have_keys;
    int* values;
};
```

Methods:

```
Dict::Dict(string key, int value)
{
    keys = new string[1];
    keys[0] = key;
    have_keys = 1;
    values = new int[1];
    values[0] = value;
}

//append a key an a value
void Dict::append(string key, int value)
{
    string* temp_keys = new string[have_keys+1];
    memcpy(temp_keys, keys, sizeof(string)*have_keys);
    temp_keys[have_keys] = key;

    int* temp_values = new int[have_keys+1];
    memcpy(temp_values, values, sizeof(int)*have_keys);
    temp_values[have_keys] = value;

    have_keys++;

    keys = new string[have_keys];
    memcpy(keys, temp_keys, sizeof(string)*have_keys);
    delete[]temp_keys;

    values = new int[have_keys];
    memcpy(values, temp_values, sizeof(int)*have_keys);
    delete[]temp_values;
}

//a = dict["hello"];
int Dict::operator[](string search)
{
    for(int i = 0;i<have_keys;i++){
        if(keys[i]==search){
            return values[i];
        }
    }
}
```

I could do this:

```
Dict dict = Dict("hello", 10);
int a = dict["hello"];
show(a);
```

However, for...

```
dict["hello"]=20;
```

How can I overload operators to do that?

I don't want this:
    dict.set("hello", 20);

Thanks!

Comment: Is this an exercise in operator overloading? If not, then use e.g. [`std::unordered_map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) like the rest of us.

Comment: `std::unordered_map<std::string, int>` should do the trick.

Comment: But it looks bad.

Comment: dict["hello"]=20;

Comment: If you don't like how it looks, you can always use `typedef` to convert it to a name you prefer: e.g., `typedef std::unordered_map<std::string, int> Dict`.

Comment: In C++, `operator[]` is used for *both* `__getitem__` and `__setitem__`. It does this by returning a reference (or a reference-like object, but those are finicky).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int& Dict::operator[](string search)
{
    for(int i = 0;i<have_keys;i++){
        if(keys[i]==search){
            return values[i];
        }
    }
    // throw here...


}
```

Return a reference to the `int` and you can assign to it in `main` using

```
dict["hello"] = 45;
```

Remember that if the Key isnt in the map then there is UB

Comment: @user9815151 you are welcome :) please upvote if you havent :) and thanks for accepting :)

Comment: I'm less then 15 reputation

Comment: This does work when the key you are searching for is in the dictionary, but this will fail and cause undefined behavior if the key isn't in the dictionary. This is because there is no return value for when the key isn't already in the dictionary.

Comment: Not a downvoter but... your answer completely ignores the standard library's builtin [ordered](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container#Associative_containers) and [unordered](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container#Unordered_associative_containers) associative containers.  In addition to which, recommending a linear search is almost always the wrong approach.  Especially since -- as pointed out by @Daniel -- failure to find the requested item results in undefined behaviour.

Comment: @G.M. thanks. OP was trying to avoid the standard containers thats why I answered something that makes use of his code. I agree I should add a warning about what happens when key is not in the map.